# Combine two Mongo db collections

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections in my mongodb server which has the same documents but one has the history data and the other has the "actual" data (2020).

I want to merge bot collections so I can connect to only one data source with the official BI connector.

I was looking for this, but I always find answers for merge or join different documents from one or another to combine data into one document but what I need is just:

HistorydataCollection:

```
{
    _id:xxxxxx
    name: jhon
    lastname: doe
    birthdate: 2019-01-02
}
```

ActualsdataCollection:

```
{
    _id:yyyyy
    name: michael
    lastname: jordan
    birthdate: 2020-01-02
}
```

NewCollection:

```
[
{
    _id:xxxxxx
    name: jhon
    lastname: doe
    birthdate: 2019-01-02
},
{
    _id:yyyyy
    name: michael
    lastname: jordan
    birthdate: 2020-01-02
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $merge.

```
db.source_collection.aggregate([{$merge:'destination_collection'}])
```